# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier

Tags: xcode

I've searched this problem extensively and none of the suggestions have worked for me.  I'm also very new at this so the problem could be something very basic.  I'm trying to create a segue from a table view controller to a view controller that has a table view on it.  When I run it in the simulator it crashes when I click on a cell and gives me this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier.

Here's my code:

```
var conditions = [Condition]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    for Location in locations {
        for Condition in Location.conditions {
            conditions.append(Condition)
        }
    }
            let selectedCondition = conditions[indexPath.row]
            let destinationVC = TestTableViewController()
            destinationVC.condition = selectedCondition
            destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("FirstSegue", sender: self)
}
```

I've tried deleting the app on the simulator, doing Product -> clean, renaming the storyboard, and I'm sure the segue is named correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier:`, you want to perform it on self: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`, because it's the presenter who presents the destination, not the destination presenting itself.